# Weird operand (t!) on postscript file

Tags: postscript

I'm trying to reverse engineer some postscript file and come across this set of commands:

```
{/@co18
37 59 63 t! (PROMO) eq
not
def}exec
```

So basically, what I'm confused about is this line:

```
37 59 63 t! (PROMO) eq
```

What's this `t!` stand for?
`eq` operand needs to take 2 objects from the stack and compare them. So from what I understand, `t!` does some calculation with the 3 numbers coming before it and saves the result in the stack. The result is probably some sort of string since it compares it with 'PROMO' later.

I don't see this `t!` defined anywhere in the code but it appears in many other places:

```
{@co3{@st2 setfont
186.71 106.80 moveto
59 22 31 t! sr }if}^ap
```

(Also, still not sure what's this `^ap` operand doing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the missing command is 'hidden' in the eexec portion of the code.
I decrypted it using Samyak answer on this question:
[How to "decode" eexec of font file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584054/how-to-decode-eexec-of-font-file)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to find the definition, its not standard PostScript and so must be defined somewhere in the program. It may be in an eexec encrypted portion.

You would need to post an example before I could comment further.

Comment: There's an eexec part at the beginning of the file. Too long to post here.
Not sure how to decrypt it.

Comment: The eexec encryption is defined in the PLRM but you'd have to write your own decryption code.  If you put the whole program somewhere like Dropbox I can take a look but not until next week.

Comment: Thanks.
I managed to decrypt the eexec portion and found the missing operands thanks to Samyak on this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15584054/how-to-decode-eexec-of-font-file